# WPF ToolBar: how to remove grip (dots on the left)

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, toolbar

I use ToolBar for my WPF application. As I understand, there is no easy way to make it floating. I just want to remove element which I don't want to be displayed: several dots in the left side of ToolBar. Is there any Properties to customize view of ToolBar? Or, maybe, it's possible to redefine a ToolBar Template?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can set attached property

```
ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"
```

It will remove the grip(dots on the left).
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just for clear, I put my ToolBar in ToolBarTray:
 <ToolBarTray IsLocked="True">
        <ToolBar/>
 </ToolBarTray>

Comment: I don't think this answer helps. Though this removes the dots on the left this also adds a inaccessible menu on the right. I find that solution even worse (from a visual point of view).